# Cognos 10.1 - Filtering a data Item or member - Report Studio

Tags: member, cognos

I need apply a filter over a data item created or existing member. For example, I want filter the 'CA' state where cities have more than 1000.000 people. But this filter will apply only for 'CA' state and not for others states. And the cities aren't showed on the crosstab. Ex:

```
  State           $ percapita
  CA              2.000.000,00  <---- only this measure is filtered, using other dimension
  TX              1.203.000,00
```

Regards,

```
 Marcelo
```

Comment: It would be helpful to expand on the question with your comments below. Also by the look of it you are using DMR, which is an impoerant thing to know (as dimensional functions are available)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list in which you put your two item "State" and "percapita". Then, make a right-click on the list and click to "go to query". Then in the left panel click on the "toolbox" and choose the "filter". Put it in the details filters. A new window appears. You can now write your expression like 
([State]='CA' and [percapita]>100000) or [State]<>'CA'

Comment: thank you for your answer. I need apply different filters in many lines, beyond a general filter. In the example above, if apply the filter ([State]='TX' and [percapita]>5000) or [State]<>'TX' in the 'TX' line, the composition of both filters produce a wrong result. Any idea how solve this issue? Regards

Comment: I need more example about the content of your base, what did you expect for the results and what are the final results. It help me to see what is wrong.

With this expression ([State]='TX' and [percapita]>5000) or [State]<>'TX' you want all the line where State is not TX plus all the line where State is TX and the percapita is upper than 5000.

Comment: Hi, I have the following table in this example:
STATE   CITY          STATUS   QTD
CA LOS ANGELES A 1
CA MODESTO         A       2
CA SAN FRANCISCO B 3
TX AUSTIN         A 4
TX HOUSTON         B 5
FL MIAMI         C 6
FL ORLANDO         B 7
I need filter two lines : Los Angeles where Status = A  and Houston where Status = B, keeping the others lines withou filters. How mentioned by you in your first answer, I tried created the following detail filter :

Comment: (caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY])='LOS ANGELES' AND caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[STATUS])='A' )  OR 
(caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY])='HOUSTON' AND caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[STATUS])='B' )  
OR 
(caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY]) <> 'LOS ANGELES' AND caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY]) <> 'HOUSTON')

But the last condition ( 
(caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY]) <> 'LOS ANGELES' AND caption([DMR].[State].[STATE].[CITY]) <> 'HOUSTON') ) invalid the all the filter.
The problem is : How to filter some lines , but keeping the others lines intacts.
tks.

Comment: I don't now exactly what is invalid the filter but I have 3 ideas.
First, is the caption really necessary ?
Second, maybe instead of using "=" choose "like".
Third, in your example you use the data directly in your source. Try to use the data from your query. So in your filter instead of using the Source tab, use the data elementary tab.